# check if validation group is valid without firing validation Client Side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Is it possible in ASP.Net to check whether validation group is valid without actually firing validation ?

Im talking about client side validation

Comment: Are you asking how to do client-side validation?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the validation error messages from being displayed?

Answer (score 5):

You can check whether validation group is valid via javascript through code.

```
var flag = Page_ClientValidate('validationgroupname');
if (flag) {
   // proceed for further validation if required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="ReloadPage()"

<script>

    function ReloadPage() 
    {
        var flag = Page_ClientValidate('ProgramDec');

        if (flag) 
        {
            window.onunload = refreshParent;
            function refreshParent() 
            {
                window.parent.location.reload();    
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```